# Installing Ubuntu onto a SD Card on Microsoft SurfaceBook 2 (UEFI)

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, uefi, sd-card

I've successfully created an Ubuntu boot-able USB Flash Drive.

Then, booted from UEFI on the SurfaceBook 2, by pressing Down "Power Button & Volume Up button at the same time".

After that, I've selected Install Ubuntu, Mounted the SD Card with ext4.

Ubuntu went through the installation process but once done it asked to restart, so I did so.

After booting up again, I got stuck in Grub with the following line:
"minimal bash-like line ......"

Can someone explain to me how to successfully install Ubuntu on an SD Card to Dual boot with Windows 10?